# Option to Disable/Enable MarkerCluster On Map by Checkbox

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/xzqpwpsm/) and let me know if there is a way that I can Disable or Enable the Markercluster on the map by checking and un checking a checkbox?

Currently what I have is a simple map enabled with MarkerCluster plugin and I am looking for a way to enabling or disabling this facility with checkbox without redrawing the map?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.247477, -123.128000);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        draggableCursor: 'move',
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    locations.length = 0;
    var markers = [];
    for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].LATITUDE, data.markers[p].LONGITUDE),
            map: map,
            title: "marker " + p
        });
        markers.push(marker);

    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Give your checkbox an id.
- If it is checked set the map property of the MarkerClusterer to the "map" variable.
- If it is not checked set the map property of the MarkerCluseter to null.

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('cluster'),'click', function() {
        var set;
        if (document.getElementById('cluster').checked) {
            set = map;
        } else { 
            set = null;
        }
        markerCluster.setMap(set);
    });
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f5baj1uq/)

working code snippet:

```js
var map;
var locations = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.247477, -123.128000);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: latlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeControl: true,
    draggableCursor: 'move',
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  locations.length = 0;
  var markers = [];
  for (p = 0; p < data.markers.length; p++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.markers[p].LATITUDE, data.markers[p].LONGITUDE),
      map: map,
      title: "marker " + p
    });
    markers.push(marker);

  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('cluster'), 'click', function() {
    var set;
    if (document.getElementById('cluster').checked) {
      set = map;
    } else {
      set = null;
    }
    markerCluster.setMap(set);
  });
});
var data = {
  "markers": [{
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Southlands Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.238137586",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.19781516",
    "ADDRESS": "5351 Camosun St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/southlands"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Captain James Cook Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2193808",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.03582905",
    "ADDRESS": "3340 E 54th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/captain-james-cook"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Chief Maquinna Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.267886314",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.05058984",
    "ADDRESS": "2684 E 2nd Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/chief-maquinna"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Oppenheimer Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2133181112521",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.058293310213",
    "ADDRESS": "2421 Scarboro Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/david-oppenheimer"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sir Charles Kingsford-Smith Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.221596674",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.0557042",
    "ADDRESS": "6901 Elliott St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-charles-kingsford-smith"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Carnarvon Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2565874222733",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.173557238565",
    "ADDRESS": "3400 Balaclava St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/carnarvon"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Dr. A. R. Lord Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2796404851544",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.03951720288",
    "ADDRESS": "555 Lillooet St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/dr-ar-lord"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "McKechnie Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.21770659",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.15401133",
    "ADDRESS": "7455 Maple St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/dr-re-mckechnie"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Waverley Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.227837226",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.05578593",
    "ADDRESS": "6111 Elliott St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/waverley"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Cunningham Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.236732227",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.05745595",
    "ADDRESS": "2330 E 37th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/george-t-cunningham"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Nootka Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.253592971",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.04294917",
    "ADDRESS": "3375 Nootka St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/nootka"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Tecumseh Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.237116273",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.07309884",
    "ADDRESS": "1551 E 37th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/tecumseh-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Jamieson Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.226906936",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.12100426",
    "ADDRESS": "6350 Tisdall St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/dr-annie-b-jamieson"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Weir Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.22957876",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.04440254",
    "ADDRESS": "2900 E 44th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/dr-george-m-weir"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Henderson Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.222569589",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.09527169",
    "ADDRESS": "451 E 53rd Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/john-henderson"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Queen Victoria Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.26718785",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.06634874",
    "ADDRESS": "1850 E 3rd Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/queen-victoria-grandview-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "McBride Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2419442301445",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.084950188923",
    "ADDRESS": "4750 St. Catherines St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/mcbride-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "King George Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.289824153",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.13644517",
    "ADDRESS": "1755 Barclay St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/king-george"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Britannia Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2752359917843",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.07192309841",
    "ADDRESS": "1001 Cotton Drive",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/britannia-secondary"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Magee Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2285538659929",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.151537987609",
    "ADDRESS": "6360 Maple St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/magee"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Kitsilano Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.262654773",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.16358941",
    "ADDRESS": "2550 W 10th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/kitsilano"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "John Oliver Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.231957151",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.09279776",
    "ADDRESS": "530 E 41st Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/john-oliver"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Lord Byng Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2595665510185",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.192530952998",
    "ADDRESS": "3939 W 16th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/lord-byng"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Templeton Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.278439094",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.06069106",
    "ADDRESS": "727 Templeton Drive",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/templeton"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Vancouver Technical Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.260755476",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.05129984",
    "ADDRESS": "2600 E Broadway",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/vancouver-technical"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Point Grey Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2372792444418",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.153406112125",
    "ADDRESS": "5350 Eest Boulevard",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/point-grey"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Gladstone Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.247612036",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.06163307",
    "ADDRESS": "4105 Gladstone St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/gladstone"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sir Winston Churchill Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.221059569",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.12561546",
    "ADDRESS": "7055 Heather St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-winston-churchill"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Killarney Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.225300105",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.04415722",
    "ADDRESS": "6454 Killarney St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/killarney"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sir Charles Tupper Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.249753502",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.09480948",
    "ADDRESS": "419 E 24th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-charles-tupper"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "David Thompson Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.220439257",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.0706316",
    "ADDRESS": "1755 E 55th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/david-thompson"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Prince Of Wales Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.244983054",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.15953565",
    "ADDRESS": "2250 Eddington Drive",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/prince-wales"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Windermere Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.246512457",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.0371743",
    "ADDRESS": "3155 E 27th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/windermere"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Eric Hamber Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.239630962",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.12579096",
    "ADDRESS": "5025 Willow St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "University Hill Sec.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.261616",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.232815",
    "ADDRESS": "2896 Acadia Road",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/university-hill"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Lord Strathcona Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2798115155978",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.091476792421",
    "ADDRESS": "592 E Pender St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/lord-strathcona"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sir Guy Carleton Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.234347747",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.03760798",
    "ADDRESS": "3250 Kingsway",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-guy-carleton"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Lord Roberts Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.286785283",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.13784476",
    "ADDRESS": "1100 Bidwell St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/lord-roberts"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Admiral Seymour Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.27859427",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.0803143",
    "ADDRESS": "1130 Keefer St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/admiral-seymour"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Macdonald Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.28072391",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.06467911",
    "ADDRESS": "1950 E Hastings St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-william-macdonald"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "David Lloyd George Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.209962412",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.13634891",
    "ADDRESS": "8370 Cartier St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/david-lloyd-george"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Brock Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.241215222",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.10063141",
    "ADDRESS": "4860 Main St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/general-brock"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Kerrisdale Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.236168246",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.17345921",
    "ADDRESS": "5555 Carnarvon St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/kerrisdale"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Lord Selkirk Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.249691953",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.06900705",
    "ADDRESS": "1750 E 22nd Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/lord-selkirk"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Nightingale Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.260059325",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.09371757",
    "ADDRESS": "2740 Guelph St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/florence-nightingale"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Gordon Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.265979903",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.17067418",
    "ADDRESS": "2896 W 6th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/general-gordon"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Henry Hudson Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.272245879",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.14935629",
    "ADDRESS": "1551 Cypress St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/henry-hudson"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Laura Secord Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.261735704",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.06022338",
    "ADDRESS": "2500 Lakewood Drive",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/laura-secord"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Walter Moberly Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.216109231",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.08434542",
    "ADDRESS": "1000 E 59th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/walter-moberly"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Trudeau Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.214454005",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.096959",
    "ADDRESS": "449 E 62nd Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/pierre-elliott-trudeau"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Van Horne Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.231566487",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.10656921",
    "ADDRESS": "5855 Ontario St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-william-van-horne"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Dickens Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.254862561",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.08294436",
    "ADDRESS": "3351 Glen Drive",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/charles-dickens"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Livingstone Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.250753337",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.09798144",
    "ADDRESS": "315 E 23rd Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/david-livingstone"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Hastings Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2826109608204",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.050577408683",
    "ADDRESS": "2625 Franklin St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/hastings"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "John Norquay Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.241424696",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.0516408",
    "ADDRESS": "4710 Slocan St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/john-norquay"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sexsmith Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.217267793",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.10879442",
    "ADDRESS": "7455 Ontario St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/jw-sexsmith"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sir James Douglas Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.215594159",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.06488106",
    "ADDRESS": "7550 Victoria Drive",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-james-douglas"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Franklin Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.282496197",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.02758566",
    "ADDRESS": "250 Skeena St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-john-franklin"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sir Sandford Fleming Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.22574769",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.07657409",
    "ADDRESS": "1401 E 49th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-sandford-fleming"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Bayview Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.266487007",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.18233379",
    "ADDRESS": "2251 Collingwood St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/bayview"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Lord Beaconsfield Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.252138376",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.05269627",
    "ADDRESS": "3663 Penticton St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/lord-beaconsfield"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Kitchener Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.250583805",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.17917598",
    "ADDRESS": "4055 Blenheim St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/lord-kitchener"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Edith Cavell Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.25290711",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.11722884",
    "ADDRESS": "500 W 20th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/edith-cavell"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Shaughnessy Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.248676076",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.14380998",
    "ADDRESS": "4250 Marguerite St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/shaughnessy"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Begbie Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2718308007739",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.038010037124",
    "ADDRESS": "1430 Lillooet St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-matthew-begbie"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Maple Grove Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2294087",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.15151486",
    "ADDRESS": "6199 Cypress St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/maple-grove"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Quilchena Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.237246211",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.15157081",
    "ADDRESS": "5300 Maple St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/quilchena"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Grandview Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.26619317",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.0743697",
    "ADDRESS": "2055 Woodland Drive",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/grandview"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Renfrew Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.251457775",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.03205805",
    "ADDRESS": "3315 E 22nd Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/renfrew"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sir Alexander Mackenzie Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.234536436",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.08671432",
    "ADDRESS": "960 E 39th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-alexander-mackenzie"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Queen Elizabeth Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.257791773",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.20112784",
    "ADDRESS": "4102 W 16th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/queen-elizabeth"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Thunderbird Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2636488913338",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.031870585582",
    "ADDRESS": "2325 Cassiar St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/thunderbird"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Trafalgar Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.250178757",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.16460607",
    "ADDRESS": "4170 Trafalgar St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/trafalgar"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Laurier Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.217762535",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.12504721",
    "ADDRESS": "7350 Laurel St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-wilfred-laurier"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sir William Osler Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.230762423",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.13266216",
    "ADDRESS": "5970 Selkirk St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-william-osler"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Bruce Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.242069088",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.02567271",
    "ADDRESS": "3633 Tanner St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/graham-d-bruce"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Queen Elizabeth Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.24893678",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.19469107",
    "ADDRESS": "4275 Crown St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/queen-elizabeth-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Tillicum Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.286263456",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.05559853",
    "ADDRESS": "2450 Cambridge St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/tillicum-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Kerrisdale Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.232868",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.177405",
    "ADDRESS": "3250 W 43rd Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/kerrisdale-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Lord Selkirk Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.245320775",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.07246012",
    "ADDRESS": "4444 Dumfries St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/selkirk-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "MacCorkindale Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2279901864655",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.029355035116",
    "ADDRESS": "6100 Battison St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/dr-hn-maccorkindale"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Chief Maquinna Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.266421544",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.04511809",
    "ADDRESS": "2882 E 4th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/chief-maquinna"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Henderson Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.221042144",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.08804322",
    "ADDRESS": "801 E 54th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/henderson-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Tyee Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.253569355",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.07382164",
    "ADDRESS": "3525 Dumfries St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/tyee"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Sir James Douglas Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.214830465",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.07329351",
    "ADDRESS": "7668 Borden St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-james-douglas-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Garibaldi Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.275416392",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.05026877",
    "ADDRESS": "1025 Slocan St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Laurier Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.210717996",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.1194453",
    "ADDRESS": "590 W 65th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/laurier-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "University Hill Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.274792",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.237384",
    "ADDRESS": "5395 Chancellor Boulevard",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/university-hill-elementary"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Dickens Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.250213062",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.08271031",
    "ADDRESS": "3877 Glen Drive",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/charles-dickens-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Mount Pleasant Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.263965733",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.09399954",
    "ADDRESS": "2300 Guelph St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/mount-pleasant"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Champlain Heights Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.220640302",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.02774835",
    "ADDRESS": "6955 Frontenac St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/champlain-heights"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Lord Roberts Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.283091711",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.12980601",
    "ADDRESS": "1150 Nelson St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/roberts-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Britannia Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2745120095296",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.071378795422",
    "ADDRESS": "1110 Cotton Drive",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/britannia-elementary"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Jules Quesnel Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.259567806",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.19253813",
    "ADDRESS": "3050 Crown St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/jules-quesnel"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "False Creek Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.267103112",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.12685921",
    "ADDRESS": "900 School Green",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/false-creek"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Champlain Heights Annex",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2140784326839",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.030549689398",
    "ADDRESS": "7835 Champlain Crescent",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/champlain-heights-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Queen Alexandra Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.26197055",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.07592057",
    "ADDRESS": "1300 E Broadway",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/queen-alexandra"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Queen Mary Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.267856423",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.20479699",
    "ADDRESS": "2000 Trimble St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/queen-mary"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Fraser Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2571713563496",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.108196899433",
    "ADDRESS": "100 W 15th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "L'Ecole Bilingue Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.258084034",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.1303864",
    "ADDRESS": "1166 W 14th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/lecole-bilingue"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Carr Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.250041653",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.12609641",
    "ADDRESS": "4070 Oak St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/emily-carr"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Wolfe Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.247228707",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.10596494",
    "ADDRESS": "4251 Ontario St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/general-wolfe"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Lord Nelson Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.272507738",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.05971209",
    "ADDRESS": "2235 Kitchener St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/lord-nelson"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Tennyson Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.262518935",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.14937705",
    "ADDRESS": "1936 W 10th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/lord-tennyson"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "McBride Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.24415661",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.07817551",
    "ADDRESS": "1300 E 29th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-richard-mcbride"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Grenfell Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2428916216093",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.034807374541",
    "ADDRESS": "3323 Wellington Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/sir-wilfred-grenfell"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Tecumseh Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.232055743",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.06800394",
    "ADDRESS": "1850 E 41st Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/tecumseh"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Elsie Roy Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.272238",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.122482",
    "ADDRESS": "150 Drake St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/elsie-roy"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Collingwood Neighbourhood School",
    "LATITUDE": "49.236551",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.03288",
    "ADDRESS": "3417 Euclid Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/collingwood-neighbourhood-bruce-annex"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Walter Moberly Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.216109231",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.08434542",
    "ADDRESS": "1000 E 59th Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/walter-moberly"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "Waverley Elem.",
    "LATITUDE": "49.227837226",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.05578593",
    "ADDRESS": "6111 Elliott St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/waverley"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "VLN - Secondary",
    "LATITUDE": "49.2319589658739",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.091869475134",
    "ADDRESS": "530 E 41st Av",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/vancouver-learning-network-secondary-0"
  }, {
    "SCHOOL_NAME": "VLN - Elementary",
    "LATITUDE": "49.275399523275",
    "LONGITUDE": "-123.049806085058",
    "ADDRESS": "1025 Slocan St",
    "URLLINK": "http://www.vsb.bc.ca/schools/vanocuver-learning-network-elementary"
  }]
};
```

```css
#box {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #F2F2F2;
}
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markerclustererplus/2.1.4/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cluster" checked="checked" />With Cluster</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```