# How to un-cluster Google Maps Clusters - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have created clusters using the following method:

```
marker_clusters = new MarkerClusterer(map, my_markers_arr, mcOptions);
```

and on request I would like to uncluster them. `my_markers_arr` contains all the markers objects created right before clustering them. So, how can I actually reverse this, or is it even possible?

I have also tried by giving a gridSize 0 but clusters still form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Option to Disable/Enable MarkerCluster On Map by Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186439/option-to-disable-enable-markercluster-on-map-by-checkbox)

Comment: @geocodezip this example doesnt exactlty shows what he is asking. It actually re creates markers everytime the user clicks in checkbox. What if you have thousands of markers in clusters? you don't wanna fetch everytime, its not efficient. Instead you want to just remove clusters but display markers.

Comment: There are many similar questions, a [mcve] would help clarify the issue, and choose right one .